# Image stored in C:\ as background for html document

Tags: html, background-image

I have this nice little line of code

```
<html style="background-image:url(file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lifehacks.png); background-repeat:repeat; background-attachment:fixed; overflow:scroll;">
```

I'm basically putting together a practice website to get used to html. When I had the background as a link to a website containing the image such as this

```
style="background-image:url(http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1381375879/lifehacks10.png)
```

It worked fine. I saved the image to my wwwroot folder, which contains my html documents. Why won't it display the image now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in the same folder as your html documents you can just do this:

```
<html style="background-image:url(lifehacks.png); background-repeat:repeat; background-attachment:fixed; overflow:scroll;">
```

Comment: So easy a caveman could do it, which makes me question my own IQ for not trying that. Thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: Sorry, it told me to wait 11 minutes but by that time I was caught up in developing my site :p